# Can I redirect all of the NDRs for my domain to a central mailbox in Exchange Online?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, email-bounces, exchangeonline, ndr

At my company our ticketing system pulls from dedicated mailboxes, but when an email is sent from one of them due to some automated process or other and fails it of course throws an NDR.  The problem is that those NDRs trigger new tickets.  What I want to do is redirect all of the NDRs from our various departments to a central inbox so they stop hitting those other inboxes at all and triggering unnecessary tickets.  I want them redirected instead of summarily deleted so that we can update the ones that are just typos and such and have records of at least trying to send them.

At first I tried just setting up a mail flow rule that diverts anything with "Undeliverable" in it, but that routed a few false positives because it searches the subject and the body, and didn't catch the test emails I was sending anyway. My searching found several threads on how to disable NDRs through Outlook or instructions on how to modify NDRs for incoming mail, but the closest thing I found to help for my particular situation was a note for Exchange 2013 saying that since NDRs are considered system messages mail flow rules are basically worthless.

Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing or is it just impossible to do anything with outbound NDRs domain-wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to [Exchange Online via Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) and run

```
Set-TransportConfig -ExternalPostmasterAddress <EmailAddress>
```

Would set it to a shared mailbox address and assign rights to it from your helpdesk/support mailbox for visibility.

You can also set it to $null and not receive any NDRs which is the default setting

```
Set-TransportConfig -ExternalPostmasterAddress $null
```

[Further reading on the Set-TransportConfig command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/configure-external-postmaster-address)

Comment: I test on my side, no matter inbound/outbound NDR, this didnt work.

Comment: According to the documentation you linked this is for external senders sending mail in, not internal trying to send out.  But I gave it a shot anyway because why not, and it definitely did not work.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In that case, I'm going to advise to contact Office365 support and they'll be able to advise. Please report back if you get an answer as I'm curious to know.

Comment: @JurajB Official word from Microsoft was that NDRs are basically soulbound to the originating address.  You can create Outlook rules for individual mailboxes to delete them or sort them into a subfolder, but you can't redirect or forward them with Outlook rules and you can't even touch them with Exchange rules.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a 3rd mail-filter softeware or firewall to handle these NDR emails.